# How do I access a button in a subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, subviews

I want to implement this fade in/out in a horizontal scroll I have, but I can't figure out how to access my button that is in a subview of my UIScrollView. This is what I'm trying to implement [Fade in/out stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875129/fade-in-out-uiscrollviews-content-like-mobile-safari-does-in-its-tab).

This is my code...

```
        Game *game = (Game *)[_schedule.games objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 20, 150, 100)];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:game.opponent] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[button setTitle:game.opponent forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_gameScrollList addSubview:button];
```

How Can I add the observer to my button, Can this be done?

```
        [self.scrollView addObserver:[self.contentViews objectAtIndex:i] 
                          forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" 
                             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                             context:@selector(updateAlpha:)];
```

Comment: let me see if a understood correctly: you have a scroll view with buttons inside it, and you want to to this fade/in/out animation when scrolling through them?? Please, be more clear in your question

Answer (score 1):

To access the reference of this button added as subview, you can:

- Use this button as a iVar, saving the reference to use it later;
- Similarly, use this button as a property;
- Iterate through subviews of _gameScrollList, looking for a subview of UIButton's class (not recommended, will work well only if it has just one UIButton as subview)

Example of how implement the second approach. Just declare a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
```

and then:

```
    Game *game = (Game *)[_schedule.games objectAtIndex:i];
    self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 20, 150, 100)];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:game.opponent] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[self.button setTitle:game.opponent forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_gameScrollList addSubview:self.button];
```

So, after, when you want to access this button somewhere, just call for the property

```
self.button.alpha = 0.5; //example of interation with your button
```

If this is not what you are looking for, you really should edit your question to be more clear.

Hope it helped.